# VHDL 4-bit AdderSubtractor error - expecting ";"

Tags: vhdl

I feel like I'm making a very simple mistake here... I'm new to VHDL, trying to make a simple 4-bit ASU but I get one which I can't figure out.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY asu is
    PORT (Cin   : IN std_logic;
            X,Y : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            S       : OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            Cout, Overflow :    OUT std_logic);
End asu;

ARCHITECTURE Behaviour OF asu IS
SIGNAL Sum : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    PROCESS (X,Y,Cin)
    BEGIN
        IF Cin = 1 THEN

            Sum <= (0 & X) - (0 & Y);
            S <= Sum(3 DOWNTO 0);
            Cout <= Sum(4); 
            Overflow <= Sum(4)XOR X(3) XOR Y(3) ;


        ELSE

            Sum <= (0 & X) +(0 & Y) + Cin;
            S <= Sum(3 DOWNTO 0);
            Cout <= Sum(4);
            Overflow <= Sum(4)XOR X(3) XOR Y(3) ;

            end IF;
            end PROCESS;
END behaviour;
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error (10327): VHDL error at asu.vhd(17): can't determine definition of operator ""="" -- found 0 possible definitions
```

Comment: I don't know VHDL, but some random guesses: on the `Cout, Overflow` line in `PORTS`, the `;` might be on the wrong side of the parenthesis. Also there's no `;` at the end of `END asu`.

Comment: "no ; at the end of END asu" was correct made a couple changes currently getting 1 error:
'Error (10327): VHDL error at asu.vhd(17): can't determine definition of operator ""="" -- found 0 possible definitions'

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare with 1 you have to compare with '1'

so you should write

```
IF Cin = '1' THEN
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression in condition `Cin = 1` requires a signature for an overloaded equality operator of [std_ulogic, integer return boolean] and there isn't one.

std_logic is a resolved std_ulogic which is an enumerated scalar type with possible values 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H' and '-'.

If you change that 1 to a '1' your analyzer will detect an "=" that will work. An equality operator between a value of a type and a value of the same type is predefined.

Also notice the four occurrences of concatenating zero with a std_logic vector (e.g. `(0 & x)`). These `0`s need to be `'0'`s as well for the same reason. There is no concatenation operator defined between an integer and a std_logic_vector.

The assignments to `s`, `cout` and `overflow` don't want to be in the process. `sum` is not in the process sensitivity list, and shouldn't be.

Deciding to add or subtract base on `cin` doesn't make any sense (to me).